# Adding function parameter to view results in error for existing computed property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to pass a function into my view, which also has a calculated property as an init value. Previously, the following code worked fine before attempting to add the function as an init property of my view:

```
var title: String
var desc: String {
    get {
        return self._desc
    }
    set {
        self._desc = newValue
        self.suggestions = newValue.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
    }
}

private var _desc: String = ""
private var suggestions:[String] = []

public init(title: String, desc: String) {
    self.title = title
    self.desc = desc
}
```

No Errors—everything works as expected. But then when I add my function to the view and in the init, suddenly it is erroring on the previous line, as if my computed property was the problem:

```
var title: String
var desc: String {
    get {
        return self._desc
    }
    set {
        self._desc = newValue
        self.suggestions = newValue.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
    }
}
var action: () -> Void
private var _desc: String = ""
private var suggestions:[String] = []

public init(title: String, desc: String, action: @escaping () -> Void) {
    self.title = title
    self.desc = desc // Errors here: "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized"
    self.action = action
}
```

I've looked at all the posts I can find with this error, but they all deal with circumstances unrelated to what I'm seeing here.

Does anyone understand what is happening? Why would adding another parameter to a view trigger this error for a computed property when otherwise it worked fine?

Answer (score 0):

So it appears the problem it had was with the order of the parameters, because the following builds without error:

```
var action: () -> Void
var title: String
var desc: String {
    get {
        return self._desc
    }
    set {
        self._desc = newValue
        self.suggestions = newValue.components(separatedBy: "\n\n")
    }
}
private var _desc: String = ""
private var suggestions:[String] = []

public init(action: @escaping () -> Void, title: String, desc: String) {
    self.action = action
    self.title = title
    self.desc = desc
}
```

Also worth mentioning is that the type of value being added as a parameter didn't matter (I tried it as a string and it was the same as when it was a function).

If anyone can explain what is going on here—I'd very much appreciate it. If you happen to run into this problem, try rearranging the order of your parameters.

Comment: The error tells you; "self used before all stored properties are initialised".   In your first code you assigned to `desc`, which will trigger the code in its `set` to run, and that code uses `self`, but you haven't yet initialised `action`, so self is used before all stored properties are initialised. When you initialise `action` first the problem goes away.